# App [unencrypted:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ubuntu

I get this error when trying to start unecrypted.js

```
PM2            | App [unencrypted:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2            | App [unencrypted:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2            | App [unencrypted:0] online
0|unencrypted  | TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function
0|unencrypted  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:20:31)
0|unencrypted  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
0|unencrypted  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
0|unencrypted  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
0|unencrypted  |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
0|unencrypted  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
0|unencrypted  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.2/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|unencrypted  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
0|unencrypted  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

This is the code from unencrypted.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var request = require('request');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var sha256 = require('sha256');
var express = require('express');
var randomMath_questions = require('random-math-question');
var randomWord = require('random-word');
var config = require('./config.js');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('echo.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('echo.crt'),
    requestCert: false
};
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(6969, '0.0.0.0');
var ExpressTrade = require('expresstrade');

var ET = new ExpressTrade({
    apikey: config.vgo_api_key,
    twofactorsecret: config.secret,
    pollInterval: config.poll_interval
});
```

The full code is here https://pastebin.com/Z0Hvjg87
Any help is very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit : `require(...).listen is not a function`.

`socket.io` is not a server, it does not listen. The [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3) says the correct syntax is :

`const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);`

Comment: i changed var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); to const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer); and now it says ReferenceError: httpServer is not defined

Comment: Obviously, because you named yours differently. Just copy/pasting code is not enough, you must adapt it to your own code.

Comment: how do i do that im kinda noob

Comment: Well, you wrote `var server = ...`, so your variable name is `server`. So use it : `const io = require('socket.io')(server)`... If you used `var BlipBlop= require('http')`, you would write `const io = require('socket.io')(BlipBlop)`